# PHP Ziparchive on hosting linux

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am using the function below to compress files, but in each directory it can automatically add two files as shown below (red Delineating).

How do I compress files while excluding these unwanted files?

[image]

```
function ziparchive($name,$folder){
  // create object
  $ziparchivename= $name.'.zip';
  //echo $ziparchivename;
  $zip = new ZipArchive();

  // open archive 
  if ($zip->open($ziparchivename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    die ("Could not open archive");
  }

  // initialize an iterator
  // pass it the directory to be processed
  $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder));

  // iterate over the directory
  // add each file found to the archive
  foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
    $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
  }

  // close and save archive
  $zip->close();
  echo "Archive created successfully.";
}
```

Comment: Try escaping the return pattern dirs (`.` and `..`) at `foreach` iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this should work.

```
$skipFiles = array('.', '..');

foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {

if(!in_array($key, $skipFiles)){
  $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
}
```

[php manual in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Another place to search is the array_search.
Another place to search is the array_search.

Comment: Check the value of $key and $value. Make sure your using the right one.